# Cardinality of a connected set of irrationals.

Tags: real-analysis

Let X be a connected subset of real numbers. If every element of X is irratioonal then the cardinality of X is,

1. infinity
2. countably infinite
3. 0
4. 1

My attempt:- Since the set of irrationals is uncountably infinite I think the answer is option 1. But the books says answer 2. Can someone help me?

Comment: It should be $4$, I'd say.  A connected set of real numbers is an interval.  If all elements are irrational, the set comprises a single number.

Comment: I guess the book is wrong then...Thanks a lot

Comment: It could be cardinality $0$ as well if you consider $\emptyset$ connected since $\emptyset \subseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @Mason That's right; I just came back to add that to my comment, but now I don't have to.

Comment: FYI, the cardinality of the **set/collection of** connected subsets of the irrationals is $c = 2^{\aleph_0}$ and the cardinality of the **set/collection of** connected subsets of the irrational points in ${\mathbb R}^2$ (i.e. both coordinates are irrational) is $2^c.$ (Exercise for whoever is interested.)